# android can't find laytout width and layout_height

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"></FrameLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
         >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in the listview and framelayout, i can't find layout_width and Layout_heigh. also, i can't find the `layout` option at all.
help please

#### Edit

this is the sdk in my mainfest

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Also, I have folder called libs and i put inside it the android support v4 libary and i added it to the eclipse.

#### edit 2

i closed the eclipse 10 times and start the windows again but still the same problem

Comment: clean your project, build again! any errors? check `Problems`view

Comment: there is no error. i tried to clean but still the same problem

Comment: There is just warnning from other projects. there is no errors at all

Comment: okay then just write them, don't wait for the eclipse to show them in the intellisense dialog

Comment: ok i can do that. but look when i go to another layout xml, i can see all of them.

Comment: it is maybe something related to `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` i am not sure yet

Comment: Please set  FrameLayout's and ListView's layout_width and layout_height

Answer (score 0):

when in eclipse you use a view from library or a custom view or custom view group it dont recognize its attrs for itself or its children so you should write them yourself.it happened for `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 0):

> the listview and framelayout, i can't find layout_width and
>   Layout_heigh. also, i can't find the layout option at all.

Then here you go:
http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android